# Cannot execute command on remote computer

Tags: c#, linux

I have Linux script and two different Solaris machines, one is `ISO-8859-1` the other is `UTF-8`

When I run it with `UTF-8` it works fine but with ISO I get an error:

How i need execute it.

if i coppy my scrit to solaris there is iso and execute there it work fine no error

My execution code:

```
using (var sftp = new Sftp())
{
  try
    {
      sftp.Connect(target.FullyQualifiedDomainName);
      sftp.Authenticate(target.UserName, crypto.TwoWayDecrypt(target.Password));
      sftp.Put(AssemblyDirectory + "\\Scripts\\solaris_perf_data.sh", "perf_data.sh", CopyMode.Copy);
    }
  finally
    {
      sftp.Close();
    }
}

ssh.Execute(chModCommand);

//error here 
result =   ssh.Execute(executeCommand).ToString();
```

The error I get is:

```
copying script file and executing script on host Solaris 10 region settings 
(france). Error Message: System.IO.IOException: ./perf_data.sh[5]: 
TotSize==+utilisés,: numéro incorrect at Dart.Ssh.Ssh.Execute(String command, 
Object state) at   Virtustream.CAS.DataCollector.Library.DataCollectors.SolarisDataCollector.GetDat‌​a(Boolean 
isInventory, String subject, String executeCommand)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @sudo_O Error copying script file and executing script on host Solaris 10 region settings (france). Error Message: System.IO.IOException: ./perf_data.sh[5]: TotSize==+utilisés,: numéro incorrect at Dart.Ssh.Ssh.Execute(String command, Object state) at Virtustream.CAS.DataCollector.Library.DataCollectors.SolarisDataCollector.GetData(Boolean isInventory, String subject, String executeCommand)

Comment: here i execute on iso , in the same seting only change to utf-8 it work fine

Comment: You should update the question with the relevant information instead of adding it in a comment. Please read the faq http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

Either you have encoding specific characters in your script (often in comments :-D) or you don't have the same permissions on your machines

Comment: @okie0th no i havent specific because if i coppy script in remote mashine end execute where it work fine

Comment: @user1406855 ssh can reset (or not) - sometimes a putty related problem - the locale on remote machine. what is the output of
ssh locale

Comment: @Okie0th # locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.ISO8859-1
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.ISO8859-1
LC_TIME=fr_FR.ISO8859-1
LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.ISO8859-1
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.ISO8859-1
LC_MESSAGES=fr
LC_ALL=